# creating FreePBX lxd container image from virtualbox instance

Tags: container, lxd, freepbx

I needed a freepbx lxd image for some test, and since I didn't find it in public image servers (well, default images: one and google search but nothing, I think for licence's issues but don't really know).

I tried to create one by installing FreePBX 15 on virtualbox, mounting the vdi (via `qemu-nbd`), tarballing it, creating a simple `metadata.yaml` and importing it on the server, but

- when I launch it seems to be in a broken state
- when I launch `lxc exec freepbxtest bash` it starts but I can see mysql is down, and
- `systemctl start mariadb` complains about polkit not running

What can be the problem? I don't really want to run it as a vm.

The lxd host is arch linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, found it, starting it and launching `lxd console freepbxtest` showed that it was trying to mount boot and other filesystems, I then removed (actually, renamed) fstab and it starts ok, with `lxc list` I can see it getting the ip form dhcp and exec-ing bash on it it shows the normal freepbx greeting so everything seems ok